# Need information for FAST Search Server 2010 for Internet Sites

Tags: performance, search, full-text-search, fast-esp

This is NOT the FAST Search for SharePoint product. I am looking for information regarding the FAST product that can be installed without SharePoint.

I've Googled and searched but can't find any more information other than the following blog - http://consultingblogs.emc.com/manjunathasubbarya/archive/2010/12/05/fsis-fast-search-for-internet-sites.aspx

I am curious if there are SMEs supporting installation and configuration. If there is any information on Microsoft's website? If anyone knows if FAST is supported outside of SharePoint.

Comment: Please see: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19821/microsoft-enterprise-search-fast-without-sharepoint

Comment: From above post: "Which are now called "FAST Search Server for Internal Applications" (FSIA) and "FAST Search Server for Internet Sites" (FSIS)." – Mikael - SharePoint MVP

Answer (score 1):

FAST Search Server for intranet sites is essentially FAST ESP 5.3, the documentation should all be relevant.